# IBM XMS.Net Listener Hangs Out when connection is closed forbiddenly

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

Hi I use webpshere mq client 8.0.0.8 and I set my listener at once and start to listen mq,but something went wrong and and myconnection is closed but it throws no error and mylistener hang out and cant listen message.If its throws error I have a mechanism to catch and restart it but that time I failed.Is there any property set to avoid this issue?

I have exceptionlistener and reconnect options in my connectionproperties.But this is not directly work,I have a autoresetevent (receiveCompleteEvent)mechanism,only solution I can find set signal in exceptionlistener,and kill connection.In exception listener I can log connection error notifications but no automatic connection set,

```
 connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, 150);

private void OnException(Exception ex)
        {
            QueueStatuslog.Error(String.Format("Unexpected error occured to connection:{0}", ex.ToString()));
            try
            {
                if (receiveCompleteEvent != null)
                {
                    QueueStatuslog.Error(String.Format("Due to connection error send stop signal:{0}", ex.ToString()));
                    receiveCompleteEvent.Set();
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting an ExceptionListener on connection? ExceptionListener will be invoked if there are any issues with connection to queue manager.

Comment: I dont set any exceptionlistener ,if any exception occurs then why it cannot be throw any exception?And If I set any exceptionlistener how can I handle this scenario?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Is this property helpful for my case?connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);

Answer (score 2):

Exception, like connection related, will be thrown to application when application makes synchronous MQ API call, like consumer.receive or producer.send. If you are using message listener to receive messages, the message delivery is an asynchronous operation and messages are delivered on the message listener thread. So XMS can not throw exceptions on that thread. Hence it requires another thread, i.e. ExceptionListener to let the application know about any connection related issues.

You will need to setup ExceptionListener on connection and catch any exception thrown. When an exception is thrown, issue Connection.Stop, clean up and reinitialize message receive.

You can also look at using automatic client [reconnection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q017800_.html) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xms_automatic_client_reconnection.html).

Comment: Defrecon=yes   we change mqclient.ini but not working ,by the way    I added this property still not solve my case,   Also I add exceptionlistener and try to throw ex still not work,only my solution is I have signal mechanism and onexceptionlistener I trigger that,is it best practise or is there any other solution connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
            connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(IBM.XMS.XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, 3600);

Comment: Can you show your code please? When you have exception listener set and reconnect set, exception listener should get notifications on connection broken and reconnect attempts

Comment: I edit my question Sashi...thanks(By the way I find a solution but I want to learn webpshere mq highavalibility best practices)

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you could post the solution you found.

Comment: I already added,sample code,I have a signal mechanism AutoResetEvent in exceptionlistener I send a signal and close the connection.I have a another schedule mechanism and if my listener is shut down it restart the listener again